# "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte" (non-ascii path name)

Tags: python, windows, powershell, unicode, path

Firstly, I have looked at all the UnicodeDecodeError questions and answers but they are mainly for people writing their own programs and I am just trying to install something.

Using pip to install some requirements for https://github.com/antiboredom/audiogrep and keep getting this error (Edited to include full traceback):

```
PS C:\Users\Oisín\audiogrep> pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting pydub==0.9.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
 Exception:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main
     status = self.run(options, args)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 339, in run
     requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 333, in prepare_files
     upgrade=self.upgrade,
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 305, in find_requirement
     page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 783, in _get_page
     return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, session=self.session)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 872, in get_page
     "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 473, in get
     return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 365, in request
     return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 461, in request
     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 610, in send
     r.content
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 730, in content
     self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 655, in generate
     for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 256
     data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 186
     data = self._fp.read(amt)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 54, in read
     self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\controller.py", line 217, in cache_
     self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 268, in set
     return super(SafeFileCache, self).set(*args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\caches\file_cache.py", line 83, in
     with FileLock(name) as lock:
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\mkdirlockfile.py", line 18, in __init__
     LockBase.__init__(self, path, threaded, timeout)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\__init__.py", line 189, in __init__
     hash(self.path)))
   File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 84, in join
     result_path = result_path + p_path
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Not sure if pip works at all for me as I haven't installed anything with it yet. The fact the error appears after the path operation is probably a good hint though. My name has an 'í' in it so that is also in the path name and presumably causing this problem. How can I fix this? (Changing the my name on the system seems unwieldy)

Windows 7, Python 2.7 and doing this in PowerShell

Comment: Please give us the **full** traceback, not just the last bit. The last bit matters but the *context* is what gives it meaning.

Comment: And since `pip` drives the `setup.py` file of a project, the error could be in a specific project. Giving us the full output from `pip` is probably prudent here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! Have edited the post to include full traceback.

Comment: This is a `pip` bug by the looks of it. What version of `pip` do you have installed? `pip -V` should show this.

Comment: "pip 6.0.8 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)"

Comment: That's the latest version, so this is not something that can be fixed with an upgrade. I see no existing bug report either; you may have to file a new bug: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues

Comment: Thanks, I've filed the new bug at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2501